# STM_SETIMAGE doesn't invalidate/repaint the static control

Tags: c++, winapi

Can anyone tell me if it's normal or not for a static control not to invalidate its area after the bitmap has been changed with the STM_SETIMAGE message?

I use a static control with the SS_BITMAP style, and I set its picture with the following code

```
    HBITMAP DestBmp;
    // Paint on DestBmp...

    HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP) ::SendMessage(hStatic, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) DestBmp);
    if (hOldBmp)
        DeleteObject(hOldBmp);

    // *** Why do I need this? ***
    ::InvalidateRect(hStatic, NULL, FALSE);
```

If I don't call InvalidateRect, the static control doesn't repaint itself. Is this the normal behaviour of STM_SETIMAGE, or am I doing something wrong? The documentation [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't mention anything about needing to call InvalidateRect after STM_SETIMAGE, and its strange anyway, you don't need to call InvalidateRect after SetWindowText for example. This makes me think something might be wrong with my code.

---

**Update**

This is how the control is defined in my .rc file

```
CONTROL         "",IDC_IMAGE_PREVIEW,"Static",SS_BITMAP | NOT WS_VISIBLE,29,293,15,13
```

The `NOT WS_VISIBLE` flag is not a problem, I make the control visible with `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);` later.

Comment: Is your window using any of the SS_CENTERIMAGE, SS_REALSIZECONTROL or SS_RIGHTJUST styles?   Those can affect if its being redrawn after a STM_SETIMAGE.

Comment: No, it doesn't have any of those flags. I've updated the question and added the definition of the control in the .rc file.

Comment: I've been trying to determine why STM_SETIMAGE wasn't updating for me as well and just found your post.  Sure enough - adding the InvalidateRect is making my code work as well, but I'd like to understand why it's necessary!

Comment: @holtavolt I added the workaround as an answer so people don't miss it. But I've switched to C# now so I'm unlikely to ever revisit that question.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no real explanation yet, and the question is getting views, I'll add my workaround here. Call `InvalidateRect()` to force the control to repaint.

```
HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP) ::SendMessage(hStatic, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) DestBmp);
.....
::InvalidateRect(hStatic, NULL, FALSE);
```