# LoadImage() in MFC Dialog loads the previously saved image. but, fails to load newly generated image to display as result?

Tags: mfc

I am working on an  MFC Dialog in VC++. In my code I have to display the processed image on the dialog (I have created a picture control (CStatic variable)). But I am facing following problem: When I press button for display result, it shows the old image instead of showing the newly calculated result image. After pressing one more time, it shows the correct result image.

I also tried with BitBlt, CreateCompatibleDC and all. But, I am facing same problem.

Here is the code:

```
SaveResultImage("result.bmp");  // This funtion saves the result image

hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"result.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);  // It should read currently saved result image

if(hBitmap)
{
    SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_PICTURE), STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);  
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for SaveResultImage.

Comment: You are leaking bitmap handles all over the place. You should be deleting not only the bitmap that you're loading, but also the one returned from the static control upon receipt of your `STM_SETIMAGE` message. If you're using MFC, why aren't you using the wrapper classes to do this? Anyway, the problem here is likely that `STM_SETIMAGE` does not cause the control to be invalidated, so it doesn't get repainted. You can force it to invalidate by calling `InvalidateWindow()`.

Comment: This is not MFC related, please set the appropriate tags. Hint for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344489/stm-setimage-doesnt-invalidate-repaint-the-static-control